# How does the 0 vector space represent a point?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

While studying Terrence Tao's Linear Algebra lectures(https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/115a.3.02f/week1.pdf)
 I stumbled upon this:

> The space $R^0$ represents vectors in a point.

Even though I understand other vector spaces it's hard for me to get the intuition for this one, why would the 0 vector space represent a point? My intuition tells me that it just represents an empty space. 
Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any vector space must, by definition of vector space, have an actual $0$ vector. So the empty set cannot be a vector space, the smallest vector space possible has one element.

It also fits very well with $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R\cong \Bbb R^{n+1}$, because if $\Bbb R^0$ is indeed a single point, then that does make $\Bbb R^0\times \Bbb R\cong \Bbb R$, while if $\Bbb R^0$ is empty, that doesn't happen. In that sense, it's somewhat of a geometric / set theoretic analogue of the empty product you may know from arithmetic and number theory: $a^0 = 1$, not $0$ (and for vector spaces with finitely many points, the connection is even stronger, as $V^n$ actually has $|V|^n$ elements).

Answer (score 0):

In every dimension, the 0 vector is just the origin, i.e. the point where each dimension is equal to 0. The problem might be that you are confusing different senses of empty: In set theory, an empty set contains nothing, while geometrically, a space with a single point like the 0 vector space is, in a sense, "empty" because it is non-dimensional. But mathematically, it is not empty because it contains a point.

Answer (score 0):

Every vector has a "direction" and "magnitude," except the zero vector. Its magnitude, which one can interpret as length, is zero.

A point does represent empty space, but the way you are thinking of empty space is different from there not being anything at all - zero is still something: having 0 toilet paper is not the same as never knowing about the existence of toilet paper. In programming, the analogy would be that of zero vs null.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb R^0$ is conventionally just the singleton $\{0\}$ endowed with the operations $0+0=0$ and $k\cdot 0=0$. This is also consistent with the set-theoretic description of $\Bbb R^n$ as the set of all the functions with domain $\tilde n:=\{x\in \Bbb N\,:\, 0\le x\le n-1\}$ and codomain $\Bbb R$: in fact, the one and only function from $\tilde 0=\emptyset$ to $\Bbb R$ is the empty function $\emptyset$.